# Suffix form_for with the record ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, each, form-for

I have an index page for moderation that also allows me to edit the records, but the problem is that the fields are named after the attribute but without the record ID.

When I do something like this:

```
- @users.each do |user|
  = form_for user do |f|
    = f.text_field :name
```

May output:

```
<form><text id="user_name"></form>
<form><text id="user_name"></form>
```

It outputs all the text fields with the same ID, when I need them to be named user_name_:id

```
<form><text id="user_name_1"></form>
<form><text id="user_name_2"></form>
```

EDIT:

For now, I'm doing the following, though I don't think it's the best way but it's a workaround at least:

```
= form_for user, as: "user_#{user.id}", html: {class: 'user_edit'} do
    = f.text_field :name, name: 'user[name]'
```

Comment: maybe i'm wrong, but if your submit button is inside the form, i don't think the names will collide (it should only send what's inside <form></form>, and only to a particular record "edit" route). Have you tried it ?

Comment: @m_x the problem is not the names colliding, is the IDs. First, there cannot be 2 elements with the same ID, and second, the labels that use for="element_id" point always to the first field with that ID.

Comment: ok, so you might want to take a look at [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7495)

Comment: see also **[this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for#357-Using-fields-for-with-has-many-associations)**